# How can I fix my csv that has nested json objects in each cell?

Tags: json, powershell, csv

My code works, but it exports data into json valued formats in a csv

```
Import-Module "$($ENV:SMS_ADMIN_UI_PATH)\..\ConfigurationManager.psd1" @initParams
# Site configuration
$SiteCode = Get-PSDrive -PSProvider CMSITE
$ProviderMachineName = "machine_name" # SMS Provider machine name
Set-Location "$($SiteCode.Name):\"


$WQL = @"
select SMS_R_System.NetbiosName, SMS_R_System.LastLogonUserName, SMS_R_System.OperatingSystemNameandVersion, SMS_G_System_BITLOCKER_DETAILS.DriveLetter, SMS_G_System_MBAM_POLICY.MBAMPolicyEnforced, SMS_G_System_BITLOCKER_DETAILS.EncryptionMethod, SMS_G_System_MBAM_POLICY.MBAMPolicyEnforced from SMS_R_System inner join SMS_G_System_MBAM_POLICY on SMS_G_System_MBAM_POLICY.ResourceID = SMS_R_System.ResourceId inner join SMS_G_System_BITLOCKER_DETAILS on SMS_G_System_BITLOCKER_DETAILS.ResourceID = SMS_R_System.ResourceId where SMS_G_System_BITLOCKER_DETAILS.DriveLetter = "C:" or SMS_G_System_BITLOCKER_DETAILS.DriveLetter = "D:"
"@
$collectionID = 'CDT003DO'
Invoke-CMWmiQuery -Query $WQL | Export-CSV C:\Test\output1
```

the output looks like the below csv, do I need to use a pscustomobject of some sort? I would like to "flatten" everything so information is all in one line

[image]

or is there a better way to export the information from SCCM? I am trying to do it in powershell so that I can create a scheduled task and have it print out the information daily

Comment: How would you like each object to look when 'flattened'?  For example, when B3 is flattened do you just want something like `DriveLetter = "C:"; EncryptionMethod = 7;` ?

Comment: yeah that would be awesome

Comment: what's the best way to do that?

Answer (score 0):

I think this should work for you.

```
# Regular Expression pattern to pluck out the text between the braces
$pattern = '(?<={[\s]{0,})[^\s][^}]*'

Invoke-CMWmiQuery -Query $WQL | 
    ForEach-Object {
        $newobj = [ordered]@{}
        # Loop through properties 
        $_.psobject.properties | ForEach-Object {
            # check for matches to our regex pattern
            if ($_.value -match $pattern) {
                # if matched, remove extra spaces and line breaks and then output this as our new property value
                $newobj[$_.Name] = $Matches[0] -replace '\s{2,}', ' '
            }
            else {
                # if not matched, output the property as-is
                $newobj[$_.Name] = $_.Value
            }
        }
        [PSCustomObject]$newobj
    } | Export-Csv C:\Test\output1.csv
```